# PHP wrong DateTime::diff() returns wrong DateInterval

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I have an issue with a difference of two Datetime. Here is the command line to display the DateInterval object :

```
php -r "\$a = new Datetime('first day of 4 months ago midnight'); \$b = new Datetime('first day of 1 month ago midnight'); var_dump(\$a->diff(\$b));"
```

And here the *DateInterval* output :

```
class DateInterval#3 (15) {
  public $y =>      int(0)
  public $m =>      int(3)
  public $d =>      int(3)
  public $h =>      int(0)
  public $i =>      int(0)
  public $s =>      int(0)
  public $weekday =>               int(0)
  public $weekday_behavior =>      int(0)
  public $first_last_day_of =>     int(0)
  public $invert =>                int(0)
  public $days =>                  int(92)
  public $special_type =>               int(0)
  public $special_amount =>             int(0)
  public $have_weekday_relative =>      int(0)
  public $have_special_relative =>      int(0)
}
```

Edit: The first and second Datetime:

```
class DateTime#1 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2014-03-01 00:00:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Zurich"
}

class DateTime#2 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2014-06-01 00:00:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Zurich"
}
```

Notice the 3 days! I'm on PHP 5.5.8 but I'm sure that this DateInterval had 0 months a few days ago. The DateInterval output 0 days in PHP 5.4.28 and the 5.5.14. I'm not sure that the PHP version has an effect.

In both cases, the days property is 92.

Comment: FYI: `$d` gives `0` on PHP 5.5.9 (WIN x86)

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.5.15RC1 and get `$d` as `0`

Comment: Can you provide the output of a `var_dump($a,$b);`?

Comment: `PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 (cli)` - same result. `$m:3`/`$d:3`/`$days:92`

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem?

Comment: ``PHP 5.4.29-3+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)`` return ``$m:3/$d:3/$days:92``

Comment: It's somewhat debatable what the correct answer is anyway. *"x months y days"* depends on how you define "a month", which is either anything from 28 to 31 days, **or** simply the numeric difference of the month numbers. Either way, if I tell you *"You'll die in 3 months and 5 days"*... when exactly are you going to die? Is that a different timespan than *"You'll die 3 months and 5 days after you meet the love of your life."*?

Comment: @deceize _March, 6_ is definitely exactly three month ago of _June, 6_, there is nothing debatable. It looks like it’s a PHP bug, which involves timezone settings (see Paul’s answer below.)

Comment: @mudasobwa But `DateInterval` expresses a *timespan*. If you say *March 6* to *June 6* is a *3 months 0 days interval*, then taking that interval and applying it to another date should yield the same result. So, *November 30th* plus *3 months 0 days* is what exactly? *February 30th*? Nope. I hope you see the problem I'm trying to express here. There's inherently a lot of problems with this stuff to begin with.

Comment: Just linking a similar QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163378/php-weird-dateinterval-length-calculation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing insight into [Paul T. Rawkeen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24931373/1481489), the problem with `DateTime::diff` is that it first [converts the timezone to UTC before computation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#109210).

```
<?php

$zurich = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich');
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$a = new DateTime('first day of 4 months ago midnight',$zurich);
$b = new DateTime('first day of 1 month ago midnight',$zurich);

var_dump($a,$b);

$a->setTimezone($utc);
$b->setTimezone($utc);

var_dump($a,$b);

?>
```

Gives the following:

```
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2014-03-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Zurich' (length=13)
object(DateTime)[4]
  public 'date' => string '2014-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Zurich' (length=13)
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2014-02-28 23:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[4]
  public 'date' => string '2014-05-31 22:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

The 3 day discrepancy is now very clear, after the timezone is converted from `Europe/Zurich` to `UTC` the dates are now `2014-02-28 23:00:00` and `2014-05-31 22:00:00` for `$a` and `$b` respectively.

---

The solution is to work entirely in UTC and convert before displaying the DateTime:

```
<?php

$zurich = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich');
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');

$a = new DateTime('first day of 4 months ago midnight',$utc);
$b = new DateTime('first day of 1 month ago midnight',$utc);

var_dump($a,$b);

$a->setTimezone($zurich);
$b->setTimezone($zurich);

var_dump($a,$b);

?>
```

Notice that all days are now `01`, albeit the hours are now a little different (see the note at the end of this answer):

```
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2014-03-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[4]
  public 'date' => string '2014-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2014-03-01 01:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Zurich' (length=13)
object(DateTime)[4]
  public 'date' => string '2014-06-01 02:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Zurich' (length=13)
```

---

To offer a bit of insight into this phenomenon, note the following:

- February has 28 days (in 2014)
- May has 31 days
- DST starts on March 30: +01:00
- Europe/Zurich is UTC+02:00

When converting from Europe/Zurich to UTC one must consider more than just the year, month and day, but the hours, minutes, and seconds too. If this was any other day than the *first* of any month, this problem would not occur, however the hours would still be 23:00 and 22:00 (pre the examples above).

Answer (score 2):

This thing depends on `DateTimeZone` you provide.

If you set `Europe/Zurich` or any `EEST` time you will get the described result.

If `GMT`/`UTC` for e.g., you will get `$d = 0`.

---

You can use global time zone definition along your project to avoid such problems (*if it suits you*)

> date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Zurich" );

or define required time zone for `DateTime` objects.

---

**UPD:** as was mentioned [below in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931166/php-wrong-datetimediff-returns-wrong-dateinterval#comment38741114_24931373), by *@mudasobwa*, this **[problem is mentioned here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#101990)** about 3 years ago.

Comment: Kiev has an additional day per month? Sounds a bit weird for me. Anyway, Barcelona, CET: `$d => 3` confirmed.

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm really doubt about it, but the difference is obvious if time zone is changed. Moreover, I tried to change DTZ between `GMT` \ `Europe/Zurich` and [**GTM** : `$d=0`] and [Zurich : `$d=3`].

Comment: @mudasobwa it appears that we're not the first to come across a problem with resolution, see this comment (3 years ago) from "schindhelm at gmail dot com": http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#101990

Comment: @mudasobwa True. Confirm.

Comment: Please re-read Paul’s answer. ou should switch *from* `Europe/Kiev` not *to*.

Comment: @PaulT.Rawkeen It was zamnuts who digged the archives.