# Bad day difference on DateInterval for march 2016

Tags: php, datetime

I have an issue with `DateInterval::$d` property with march 2016.

See the code:

```
$date1 = new \DateTime('2016-07-01');
$date2 = new \DateTime('2016-07-31');

$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2, true);

var_dump($diff->d); // int(0) => OK

$date1 = new \DateTime('2016-03-01');
$date2 = new \DateTime('2016-03-31');

$diff = date_diff($date1, $date2, true);

var_dump($diff->d); // int(1) => NOT OK
```

On the second example, I have 1 month difference (that is normal) and 1 **extra** day.

I don't understand at all why and I don't have this issue with another 31 days' month.

Is that a PHP bug or a bad usage of this property?

Comment: I get `int(30) int(30)`

Comment: @j08691 with which php vers? me also obtain OP result. Note that the cmd is `->d`, not `->days`

Comment: @fusion3k 5.6 or 7. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/815db837b847c7315a87903b0b2c0a7c4b01f799

Comment: The problem is TimeZone related, but I don't know the reason. March is the Daylight Saving Time month in most parts of the world, and this could maybe explain the additional day (but... really?). Anyway, I don't understand why `->m` is 1: actually, the correct result should be 0 month, 30 days.

Comment: @fusion3k is right (try to use 2016.11.01-30 - you will get 29 days). But still it strange. Why if you var_dump object it returns 0 hours for $diff->h. Shouldn't it consider daylight saving if days and months are doing it?

Comment: @Jakub I have tested with many (not all) TimeZone. It seems affect only positive tz (GMT+1, GMT+2, etc)

Comment: See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#101990) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24931746/3294262)

Comment: I opened a PHP issue just in case: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71700