# Calculating age in php using $date->diff returns wrong value

Tags: php

I am calculating age of a person as follows-

```
$dob = new DateTime('01-03-2004', new DateTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka"));
$to = new DateTime("28-02-2022", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka"));
$interval = $dob->diff($to);
```

It returns 17 years 11 months 29 days.

But [calculator.net](https://www.calculator.net/age-calculator.html?today=03%2F01%2F2004&ageat=02%2F28%2F2022&x=112&y=16) shows
17 years 11 months 27 days.

Is there any other technique to calculate age in php?

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Executing you code shows 27 days, not 29 days.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Dn6dV - 2 different versions of PHP and 2 different outputs

Comment: I am getting 29 days. My php version is 8.0.1

Comment: Try it in UTC instead of Asia/Dhaka. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24931746/17218429

Comment: Example code, converting dates to UTC before Difference calc. https://3v4l.org/VO24G

Answer (score 0):

The difference is due to your time zone. Try using this:

```
$dob = new \DateTime('01-03-2004');
$to = new \DateTime("28-02-2022");
$interval = $dob->diff($to);
```

Without time zone specified, it will give you, your desired result.

Output:

```
DateInterval {#721 ▼
  interval: + 17y 11m 27d
  +"y": 17
  +"m": 11
  +"d": 27
  +"h": 0
  +"i": 0
  +"s": 0
  +"f": 0.0
  +"weekday": 0
  +"weekday_behavior": 0
  +"first_last_day_of": 0
  +"invert": 0
  +"days": 6573
  +"special_type": 0
  +"special_amount": 0
  +"have_weekday_relative": 0
  +"have_special_relative": 0
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting 27 days.

Comment: @s.k.paul did you remove the time zone?

Comment: If you already removed the timezone from the object. There must be another instance or a global variable or property that is overriding the timezone in that object. You can use "UTC" as a parameter in the `DateTime()` object to override any predefined or default timezone.